# Why this loop become infinite loop in C?

Tags: c, unsigned, unsigned-integer

Here in this code, I am using unsigned int and want to terminate my loop as soon as it reaches '0'. But this never happens it passes '0'

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned int uint32_t ;

delay (uint32_t x){
    uint32_t y = 0;
    for(y=x; y>= 0; y--){
         printf("Display number %d\n", y);
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t times = 10;

    printf("Hello World!\n");
    delay(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
Display number 10
Display number 9
Display number 8
Display number 7
Display number 6
Display number 5
Display number 4
Display number 3
Display number 2
Display number 1
Display number 0
Display number -1
Display number -2
Display number -3
Display number -4
Display number -5
Display number -6
```

[Link: For code from: code.hackerearth.com](https://code.hackerearth.com/389205g)

Comment: It will go on until `y` becomes negative. `y` is unsigned so it cannot become negative

Comment: `y` is un *unsigned* integer (`uint32_t`) so it is *always* `>= 0`. So `uint32_t y = 0; for(y=x; y>= 0; y--)` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `for(y=x; y>= 0; y--){` `y` can never be below 0 since it's an unsigned type. Once y is 0, `y--` will *wrap around* to `std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()`. So the `for` loop never terminates.

The fact that `printf` is displaying negatives is a manifestation of the *undefined behaviour* on your using an incorrect format specifier for an unsigned type.

Comment: Yes I know the problem now, it was %d that mislead me thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

An `unsigned` number will always be bigger or equal 0.

Your compiler should warn you about this error.

The reason why you are seeing negative numbers in the output is that you are printing the unsigned number using `%d`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer : -)

Answer (score 0):

An unsigned number will always be bigger or equal 0.

Change this

```
delay (uint32_t x){
    uint32_t y = 0;
    for(y=x; y>= 0; y--){
         printf("Display number %d\n", y);
    }
}
```

with

```
delay (uint32_t x){
    int y = 0;
    for(y=(int)x; y>= 0; y--){
         printf("Display number %d\n", y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`y` is *unsigned*, therefore it will never be negative. You can either define it as `int`

```
int y = 0;
```

or modify your `for` to a `do` `while`

```
y = x;
do {
     printf("Display number %d\n", y);
} while (--y >= 0);
```

Comment: I like the second idea, but the OP needs to fix the UB due to the incorrect format specifier.